# Atualizar atributos de componentes filhos

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

Estou fazendo um componente de accordion bem simples. Uma lista de items onde clico em um e ele abre; caso já tenha algum aberto, ele fecha e o outro abre.

```
<ns-accordion-item is-show="false">
  <accordion-head>
    <h3> Este títlulo pode conter o que quizer</h1>
  </accordion-head>
  <accordion-body>
      <form>[...]</form>
  </accordion-body>
</ns-accordion-item>
```

Esse carinha é um componente bem simples, ele faz o transclude de `<accordion-head>` e `<accordion-body>`. O body tem um `ng-if` da prop `is-show` (bind '='), então só exibe o conteúdo quando necessário.

Quero criar um outro componente, o `<ns-accordion>`.
A ideia é que ele controle e deixe apenas um `<ns-accordion-item>` aberto.

Então, ficaria algo assim:

```
<ns-accordion>
  <ns-accordion-item>[...]</ns-accordion-item>
  <ns-accordion-item>[...]</ns-accordion-item>
  <ns-accordion-item>[...]</ns-accordion-item>
</ns-accordion>
```

E agora é que não sei fazer a mágica acontecer.

Tentei fazer com que o `<ns-accordion>` alterasse o attr `is-open` do `<ns-accordion-item>` lá no $postLink

```
ctrl.$postLink = function() {
  $currentAccordion = $element.find('ns-accordion-item[is-show="true"]');

  $element.on('click', 'ns-accordion-item', function(){
    var $el = angular.element(this);
    $currentAccordion.attr('is-show', false);
    $currentAccordion = $el.attr('is-show', true);
  });
};
```

Apesar dele alterar o atributo, o accordion-item ignora essa alteração e não dispara o $onChange.

Alguém sabe onde estou errando? Isso é a boa solução?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar `$emit` no `$scope` dos seus `ns-accordion-item` para notificar o `ns-accordion` quando eles forem clicados, assim o `ns-accordion` usa `$broadcast` para notificar os `ns-accordion-item` que eles devem fechar.

O `$emit` emite um evento para os escopos pais de onde foi emitido.

O `$broadcast` emite um evento para os escopos filho de onde foi emitido.

Assim você faz seus componentes conversarem com suas devidas árvores de escopo. Talvez de problema caso você insira um conjunto de `ns-accordion` e `ns-accordion-item`, mas ai você consegue fazer um workaround usando ids para os `ns-accordion`.

Doc `$emit` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit

Doc `$broadcast` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast

Comment: valeu. Fica como PubSub, massa 

Pensei em outra coisa também. Quando criamos um `form` o `scope` pai ganha uma prop com o nome do formulário.

Então pensei em fazer algo assim:

`<ns-accordion name="acc">` `<ns-accordion-item name="sub1" is-open="$acc.sub1.isOpen">`

O que acha?